# string to ascii in longer byte array

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I want to convert string into ascii and storing it into byte array. I know the simplest way for this is

> Encoding.ASCII.GestBytes

but what I want is

```
byte[] temp = new byte[];
temp = Encoding.ASCII.GestBytes("DEMO1");
```

Thus when I do

> Console.WriteLine(temp[i])

it should print out 68 69 77 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 instead of 68 69 77 48

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that if the buffer is too much small, this will throw:

```
byte[] temp = new byte[10];
string str = "DEMO1";
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str, 0, str.Length, temp, 0);
```

There is no easy way, compatible with UTF8, to handle it (because UTF8 has variable-length characters). For ASCII and other fixed length encodings you could:

```
byte[] temp = new byte[10];
string str = "DEMO1";
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str, 0, Math.Min(str.Length, temp.Length), temp, 0);
```

Or, in general you could:

```
string str = "DEMO1";
byte[] temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
Array.Resize(ref temp, 10);
```

and this would work even with UTF8.